# How to get C++ function names in hg diffs?

Tags: c++, mercurial, diff

I would like to get the C++ function names in a file. I tried do this with the command diff because I only need get the name of the function which is modified but I could not get it. 
I know that with python files it is possible using git with the option 'git diff file.py'. 
Is it possible do it with c++ files in Mercurial?

Comment: `git diff -p` doesn’t list functions in any language, it generates a patch file. (And it’s the same as `git diff`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the config option `diff.showfunc`. The doc (`hg help config`) says:

```
"showfunc"
    Show which function each change is in.
```

It's working fine for Python functions and I think the heuristic should work similarly for C++ files. Maybe it will need functions body to be indented to correctly detect C++ functions.